# Deployed .WSP via powershell, but now jquery wont work

Tags: web-part, deployment

I followed the steps in [This](http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.com/2013/06/deploying-wsp-to-sharepoint-2013.html) article to deploy my solution, which uses some jQuery. however now that I've deployed it, it doesn't work. what can I do to get this working again?
It worked perfect in my development server but now...nothing. this is for SharePoint 2013.
The jQuery files are on the right location on the server.
The script simply scrolls the contents of a list using:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#NewsTicker').vTicker({
        speed: 500,
        pause: 3000,
        showItems: 1,
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: true,
        direction: 'up'
    });
});
```

As I say, it owrked on the development server but not on the production server. Is it a permissions thing.
When I go to the settings page->web parts and click on the little icon under "type" it will show the webpart working fine.

[image: Image when its on the page. showing both items at once]Image when its on the page. showing both items at once
[image: Image showing single item ready to scroll. on web part management page]Image showing single item ready to scroll. on web part management page

****Now i find it works on other pages, just not the home page which is a wiki****

Comment: Can we get more details on what your script trying to do?

Comment: Any errors on the browser's console?

Comment: nothing in the console

Comment: I found that I have two web parts using jquery. One oerrides the other. Nay reason form this?